# Adding a map to Watchkit Extension

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am following this talk for building a watch kit app extension for my app, specifically the 'build interfaces' section: https://realm.io/news/building-watchkit-apps-swift/

When I run my project I get the following compiler errors in my bridging header file:

> Yelp/Yelp-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: 'NSDictionary+BDBOAuth1Manager.h'
>   file not found
>
> Failed to import bridging header '/Yelp/Yelp-Bridging-Header.h'

Both of these errors are appearing in the WatchKit Extension.

This is my code on the bridging header file:

```
//  Yelp-Bridging-Header.h
//  Yelp

#import "NSDictionary+BDBOAuth1Manager.h"
#import "BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"
```

Do I need a new bridging header in my WatchKit extension folder?

Comment: IIRC yes. Extensions and apps themselves don't share code unless you make them members of both.